# mercurial to git branch issue

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket

I converted a mercurial repo into a git repo using following this site https://helgeklein.com/blog/2015/06/converting-mercurial-repositories-to-git-on-windows/.It did not mention that it would not copy all the branches. In the mercurial repo they were named branches but when I converted it a git they changed '.git\objects....', which they all seem to be from my develop branch, but I need my other branches in the repo. I need to know how do I go about adding the branches that is missing. I want to be able to add to the rest of it and I need to know if the link that I followed was the best course of action or if there is something missing to it. Any help on my problem would be great. I have tried also using fast-export but that did not work either. I am willing to try any other ideas if anyone can provide some course of action. I am using BitBucket as the site where my repo's reside.

Answer (score 1):

regretfully in Git there are no named branches,
so the migration cannot come up with nothing like them

the migration should have created bookmarks instead,
since Git's branches are more close to Mercurial's bookmarks than to actual "named branches"

you might be interested in reading https://felipec.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/mercurial-vs-git-its-all-in-the-branches/

notice that if you are used to Mercurial, likely you'd miss them for a while,
but eventually you'll get use to "the git way" and you'll survive, I hope ;-)

Comment: So would i then have to create a bookmark for each branch in a way?

Comment: I haven't reproduced your steps. I use hggit extension integrated in my TortoiseHg so I keep working in both Hg and Git and push/pull between both, and yes, it creates bookmarks (it also may give some headaches on certain scenarios, but I have figure it out already)

Comment: I did use the hggit extension intergrated in my tortoiseHg but I also use source tree and source tree is not to fond of having a .git folder and a .hg folder in one. It sometime gives a major error. Should I rather just stick to using tortoiseHg then and figure out how to go about creating bookmarks?

Comment: creating a bookmark is straightforward and you can undo whenever you want, it doesn't leave any residual once deleted, you can create, rename, move, delete, and create again, as many times as you want, you can be confident that there is no complexity about it. They are just a "label" to alias a commit, same as Git branches are

Comment: I believe that hggit has options to automatically setup the right bookmarks to correspond to git branches. You shouldn't have to do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

1. Any posts from 2015 about Mercurial|HGGit are *extremely outdated* in a lot of areas (even more fresh topic /last edit Jan 8, 2020/ in [Mercurial Wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgGit) have some sections marked as "outdated") and probably best source will be [readme from hggit repo](https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/hg-git/blob/branch/default/README.md)
2. If you can get *working* hggit in THG (it's hardest and most time-consuming part of work), interacting with Git will be rather straightforward

   - **Every** named branch of Mercurial must have linked bookmark to it in order to interoperate with Git-repo. You can add bookmarks by hand or use (released after for 2015 and thus not covered in article) `branch_bookmark_suffix` feature for auto-creating and auto-naming
   - Without handwork and patches of code you'll not be able to push to Git-repo over https if authentication is required on remote (and this /authentication/ is true for 99.99% of cases), easiest solution will be just move to `git+ssh://` (if remote-side support it, obviously)

PS: I *have and use* local TortoiseHG 5.0.2+hggit for working with my Git-repo on GitHub, I can answer on any related questions more deeply, if needed